# Cloning single image to multiple drives

Tags: linux, hard-drive, partitioning, ssd

I'm looking for  a way to clone single disk drive to more than one disk drive at the same time.
and i find linux command.

```bash
dd if=/dev/sda bs=128M | bzip2 > /media/usb/image.bz2 -> make image command

bzcat drive.image | pv -p -t -e | tee >(dd bs=4M of=/dev/sda) >(dd bs=4M of=/dev/sdb) >(dd bs=4M of=/dev/sdc) | dd bs=4M of=/dev/sdd -> copy to image
```

The capacity of my ssd is 1TB, and it comes out about 12GB when I compress the image.

Is it correct command and is there a way to proceed faster?

Comment: Why was DD-WRT tagged?

Comment: `dd` is not the only tool that can read or write to a device. Unless you have a good reason for these `bs=4M`, the `tee` part of the second pipeline can be simplified to `tee /dev/sda /dev/sdb /dev/sdc >/dev/sdd`.